# How to get AWS credentials from Identity Pools (Federated Identities) with android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am new to AWS Cognito.

From my program, I want to get AWS temporary credentials to access API services such as api from API gateway.  What I have is "**IdentityPoolId**", "**IdentityId**" and "**OpenIdToken**".

When I tried accessing with AWS Credential by **getCredentialsForIdentity**, I got "**Identity 'ap-northeast-1:xxxx' not found.**" at onError method everytimes. Please help me what I was wrong?

```
    Single<GetCredentialsForIdentityResult> primeSingle = Single.fromCallable(MyClass::getResult);

    primeSingle
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new SingleObserver<GetCredentialsForIdentityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(@NonNull GetCredentialsForIdentityResult result) {
                    Credentials credentials = result.getCredentials();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                    Log.d("Test", "onError: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            });
```

Here is getting Credential Result code.

```
private static GetCredentialsForIdentityResult getResult() {
    AmazonCognitoIdentity identityClient = new AmazonCognitoIdentityClient(new AnonymousAWSCredentials());

    Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<String, String>();
    logins.put("cognito-identity.amazonaws.com", MyClass.OPEN_ID_TOKEN);

    GetCredentialsForIdentityRequest getCredentialsForIdentityRequest =
            new GetCredentialsForIdentityRequest()
            .withIdentityId(MyClass.IDENTITY_ID)  // Not Identity Pool Id
            .withLogins(logins);
    getCredentialsForIdentityRequest.setIdentityId(identityId);
    GetCredentialsForIdentityResult result = identityClient.getCredentialsForIdentity(getCredentialsForIdentityRequest);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got Credentials by referencing this.

[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html](http://Finally,%20I%20got%20Credentials%20by%20referencing%20this.%20%20https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html%20%20Thanks%20in%20advance.)

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
public class DeveloperAuthenticationProvider extends AWSAbstractCognitoDeveloperIdentityProvider {

private static final String developerProvider = null;

public DeveloperAuthenticationProvider(String identityPoolId, Regions region) {
    super(null, identityPoolId, region);
    // Initialize any other objects needed here.
}

// Return the developer provider name which you choose while setting up the
// identity pool in the &COG; Console

@Override
public String getProviderName() {
    return developerProvider;
}

// Use the refresh method to communicate with your backend to get an
// identityId and token.

@Override
public String refresh() {

    // Override the existing token
    setToken(null);

    // Get the identityId and token by making a call to your backend
    // (Call to your backend)


    // Call the update method with updated identityId and token to make sure
    // these are ready to be used from Credentials Provider.

    update(identityId, token);
    return token;

}

// If the app has a valid identityId return it, otherwise get a valid
// identityId from your backend.

@Override
public String getIdentityId() {
    // Load the identityId from the cache
    identityId = "ap-northeast-1:xxxx";
    return identityId;
}}
```

Call above call from one method:

```
private static AWSSessionCredentials getResult(Context context) {
    DeveloperAuthenticationProvider developerProvider =
            new DeveloperAuthenticationProvider("ap-northeast-1:your_pool_id", Regions.AP_NORTHEAST_1);
    CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider( context, developerProvider, Regions.AP_NORTHEAST_1);
    return credentialsProvider.getCredentials();
}
```

And use rxjava to get response:

```
Single<AWSSessionCredentials> primeSingle = Single.fromCallable(() -> getResult(this));

    primeSingle
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new SingleObserver<AWSSessionCredentials>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(@NonNull AWSSessionCredentials result) {
                    String secretKey = result.getAWSSecretKey();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                    Log.d("Test", "onError: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            });
```

After successful, you can get Credentials from onSuccess method.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20149329)

Comment: Okay. I will put it.